# Can I use ID-based link to read document using Server-side Javascript in Azure DocumentDb?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing a server-side stored procedure in JavaScript to bulk-insert documents into my documentDb collection. I also want to update a metadata document after inserting my main document. I already know the id of my metadata document.
According to my research, I understand that instead of using:

```
collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, 'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id = "' + metadataDocId + '"', callback)
```

I should be using:

```
collection.readDocument(documentLink, options, callback)
```

My question is, can I use [**ID-based document link**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/) (since I know all the IDs) or am I restricted to use the self link only? The official documentation does not specify anything.

The reason for my question is that the C# client API used to support only self-links, but now it supports ID-based link too. Does this support extend to the javascript API as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ID-based links](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/) should work fine despite the lack of clarity in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. In the [JavaScript API](https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/Collection.html#getAltLink#:%7E:text=getAltLink()%20%E2%86%92%20%7Bstring%7D), `Collection.getAltLink()` is convenient for getting the Id-based link of the collection. You can append the document Id to that using the format described in [Azure DocumentDB bids fond farewell to Self-Links](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/#:%7E:text=dbs%2FMyDatabaseId%2Fcolls%2FMyCollectionId%2Fdocs%2FMyDocumentId). In the examples below, `__` is the alias to `getContext().getCollection()`.

```js
var link = __.getAltLink() + "/docs/" + id;
```

Now you can use `link` for the operations that take a document link argument:

- `readDocument()`
- `replaceDocument()`
- `deleteDocument()`
- `createAttachment()`
- `queryAttachments()`
- `readAttachments()`
- `upsertAttachment()`

An example for `readDocument`:

```js
__.readDocument(link, {}, function (err, resource, options) {
        // callback code ...
    });
```